# Creating mercator projection for Mars planet in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mars

I would like to insert a new SRC in QGIS, like a Mercator projection for Mars.

I selected personalised projection in "preference" icon. I clicked on add a new SRC:

```
Name: MarsMercator 
parameters: +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=3396190 +b=3376200 +units=m +no_defs
```

Then I saved this new projection.

However, when I chose this new projection, my raster layer is not visible.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you right-click on the layer, Properties, Metadata tab, Properties window: What extent is reported for the layer?